# "Import "django.http" could not be resolved from source"

Tags: python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code

[The problem is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JievZ.png). Just started learning Django by following the official documentation and came across this error. Naturally, I googled it to try and find a fix, but nothing helped. Everybody is saying to choose the right interpreter, but for me the right interpreter was chosen from the start, the one in the virtual environment folder (idk if that's how you say it, like I said I'm new so the terminology is still confusing) and it is still not working.

Comment: Not very clear, but it seems you might need to install Django to your virtual environment. Need more info for better answer. Did you create a virtual env? Are you using VSCode? Where are you getting the error? It might also be that you are clicking on the "Run" button when you need to run the server...

Comment: @MoLoW I'm sorry for being unclear:
Yes - I did create a environment, I am using VSCode, and no, I am not trying to run the server. 
I will add a picture to show you where is the problem

Comment: That is not an error, it just means that VSCode cannot get the definition for Pylance, you can ignore it. You should be ok. If it really bothers you, look into the VSCode Extensions and get one with Django Definitions, or just update Pylance Extension. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=django&target=VSCode&category=Programming%20Languages&sortBy=Relevance

Answer (score 2):

This problem is probably solved by now, since it's been posted for a while. Nevertheless, this post is the first link proposed when googling the problem. So I wanted to share with you HERE what I did to solve this.

It is for sure a problem with the interpreter but, here's how to solve it:

**From Django documentation:**

> **"The command presents a list of available interpreters that VS Code
> can locate automatically (your list will vary; if you don't see the
> desired interpreter, see Configuring Python environments). From the
> list, select the virtual environment in your project folder that
> starts with ./.venv or ..venv:"**

so basically, open the command palette (Ctrl+shift+P for win) and:

1. type "Python select interpeter" click that option and a new selection list will drop down named "select interpreter".
2. Choose "+ select interpreter path"
3. Choose "Find... browse your files.."
4. Go to your Django project folder, open your virtual enviroment folder, and follow this path... venv(or whatever your v.enviroment was called)/scripts/...
5. In that folder select the Python interpreter and that should be it.

This helped me solve this issue, hope it works for another lost soul like me ...

Answer (score 1):

go to view in Vscode select command palette, then select python select interpreter there are two bit options. change from your current one from global or recommended

Comment: This fixed it for me especially when you have a venv set up

Answer (score 0):

This is probably well and truely resolved by now, but I suspect the problem was that the OP hand not selected the correct pyenv/venv in vscode.

By default vscode would have been using the system python for pylance, which (if the OP was using venvs correctly) probably didn't have Django installed. Django was probably installed in a specific pyenv/venv for the project.

On the right side of the status bar running along the bottom of vscode you can select the python install to use for the open project, always ensure you have the correct pyenv/venv selected here to avoid pylance or lint throwing errors about library's not being resolvable or missing.