# Yellow line showing under import module statements

Tags: visual-studio-code

I see this is a problem, but the program still runs. Where is the problem?

[image: Screenshot.]

I can't solve this on my own even if I search it online. I need a pointer to where I can solve this problem.

Comment: What does it say on the `Problems` tab down near the bottom?

Comment: app.models.Cart.DoesNotExist: Cart matching query does not exist.

Comment: May or may not apply in this case: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*).

Comment: At the very least it shouldn't be a dump of the entire (maximised) window (most is irrelevant).

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2874 check answer here, select interpreter in easy words search for python.exe file in environment folder ex: activate\Scripts\python.exe

Answer (score 2):

Those yellow lines means that the imported modules cannot be located.

This probably means that you downloaded the modules into a virtual environment and the modules are not installed globally. You are probably running the script with the correct virtual environment. Open your [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and choose the correct Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

For me, modules who have a yellow line under them are ones that your program doesn't need.  If I import a module that my program doesn't need functions from, a yellow line will show under it.
To fix this issue, hover over the statement with the yellow line under it, then click on `Fix Issue`.  A list will appear, with the first item probably being `Remove unused import statements`.
If, however, the list item says something like `Select Python interpreter`, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75222182/20585541) answer would fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

probably solved, similar thing happened to me and I posted about it.. take a look at this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76335963/19489427

hopefully it helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

change your python interpreter from 3.10 global to 3.11. This worked for me and maybe works for you as well. To change interpreter ctrl+shift+p write python interpreter and change it accordingly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).